# selenium python beautifulsoup stuck on currentpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a public facebook group using beautifulsoup, I am using the mobile site for the lack of javascript there. So this script supposed to get the link from the 'more' keyword and get the text from p tag there, but it just gets the text from the current page's p tag. Can someone point me the problem? I am new to python and everything in this code.

```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
   from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import requests
   browser = webdriver.Firefox()
   browser.get('https://mobile.facebook.com/groups/22012931789?refid=27')
   for elem in browser.find_elements_by_link_text('More'):
      page = requests.get(elem.get_attribute("href"))
      soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
      print(soup.find_all('p')[0].get_text())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always useful to see what your script is actually doing, a quick way of doing this is by printing your results at certain steps along the way.

For example, using your code:

```
for elem in browser.find_elements_by_link_text('More'):
    print("elem's href attribute: {}".format(elem.get_attribute("href")))
```

You'll notice that the first one's blank. We should test for this before trying to get requests to fetch it:

```
for elem in browser.find_elements_by_link_text('More'):
    if elem.get_attribute("href"):
        print("Trying to get {}".format(elem.get_attribute("href")))
        page = requests.get(elem.get_attribute("href"))
        soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
        print(soup.find_all('p')[0].get_text())
```

Note that an empty `elem.get_attribute("href")` returns an empty unicode string, `u''` - but pythons considers an empty string to be false, which is why that `if` works.

Which works fine on my machine. Hope that helps!

Comment: ah, the code was working fine way .. the  tag p was wrong,
I just changed to the proper data section I wanted,
but thanks anyway I am new to python and anything I learn is good.